# How do I call remote functions in the sqlsrv API in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, api, function

That's pretty much the question. I made a stored function that returns a bigint, and I want the return value to be stored in a PHP variable. The script uses the sqlsrv API (since the mssql one doesn't work with SQL Server 2008). How do I do it? I can't find documentation anywhere and it seems like the call procedure doesn't work, neither does the exec one.

Answer (score 0):

User Defined Functions are called on value request. It can be inside an SQL query, or within a `SET` command.

Example:

```
SET @myVariable = MyUserDefinedFunction(@parameter)
SELECT MyUserDefinedFunction(@parameter2),@myVariable
```

That's it.
Now, in this example, you can access the result of the query, like in any other query.

By the way, next time you ask a question, be more precise:

- Is it User Defined Functions, or Stored Procedures?
- What kind of API are you using?
- Some code maybe?

Comment: However, how do I return that value to the PHP variable?

Comment: How would you do it in a regular SELECT? I can't answer this question, as the only hint you've given about this is `API`. Which one? I have no idea.

Comment: Wait, that means that I can write this as a regular query, then execute it as a normal query? Can I separate lines with a semicolon?

Comment: It's a user defined function. The API I'm using is named sqlsrv. Both were stated in my question. About the code, it's unneccesary, since I'm making a general question about how to do something and there's no code to show. Posting my function would be useless.

Comment: Ok, then use the functions which @Carlos (not you. Wow, same nicknames) showed, and for the query, use what I wrote.

Comment: @AlexanderMP I have changed my nickname. Really it's a good idea, because "Carlos" it's my real name and there are to many people named Carlos. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt == false)
{
      print_r( sqlsrv_errors());
}else{
     $result_set = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
     var_dump($result_set);
}
```

No???

Comment: Yep, but how do I write the query? Using call or exec?

Comment: Look this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldriverforphp/thread/e6cdf9cb-78ed-4667-a16c-a9d5c00d0fec

Comment: Thank you, but, what about "functions"? Is there any difference on how I call a function instead of a procedure?

Comment: Si te llamas Carlos, espero que hables español. La verdad, no tengo mucha experiencia en esa lib en concreto o con MSSQL, pero realmente cuando he trabajado en otros entornos como postgres, tanto con funciones como con procedimientos no hay ninguna diferencia en cómo se devuelven los datos al cliente. Por lo que veo el código del enlace el valor retornado por el procedimiento lo esta cargando directamente en una variable que se indica como parámetro de salida. 
No se si te puedo ayudar mucho más... pero cual es el problema concreto? No puedes obtener el valor aun?

Comment: Lo logré de todos modos. Posteo la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

```
$query = "SELECT functionname(?,?,...,?) AS alias";
$bindvars = array($bindvar0,...,$bindvarn);
$resultset = sqlsrv_query($query, $connection, $bindvars);
$alias = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultset);
```

And we get the result with $alias['alias'].